# deleteInBackgroundWithBlock always return true

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've been delving into swift and using the Parse SDK and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the following:

I am trying to delete an object in the Parse DB, and have set the method up to fail - but it fails to fail.

```
func destroy(onComplete: Bool -> Void) {
    let object = PFObject(className: "ClassName")

    object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        NSLog("Error: \(error)")
        if let error = error {
            onComplete(false)
            NSLog("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            onComplete(success)
        }
    })
}
```

When I set the objectId property the object is destroyed fine, but here I am omitting it so, obviously, nothing is destroyed, but when the closure runs, success is always equal to true, and error is always nil.

Does anyone know if this is intended behaviour, because if no object is destroyed, surely, either success should equal false, or error should be non-nil?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: I think error is returning nil because you are never setting a value to error when you declare it with "let error". Try if error != nil instead.

Comment: @mn1 error is a callback parameter

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Why are you are trying to delete an object which has never been saved? I'm also not sure what you mean by "when I set the objectId property". You should ***never*** need to set the `objectId` property of a Parse object. The objectId is automatically made for you when the PFObject is instantiated.

Comment: @Russell I was simply trying to force an error to begin with, so that I can make sure it is handled as it should be. After that I'll deal with the happy path.

Comment: @mn1 The NSLog of error above the if line always outputs nil, so it appears error is always nil in this case. Therefore the if statement always returns false and the code in the else clause is what runs - this is as expected when error is nil. I was wondering why, in what appears to be an error situation, success is always true, and error is always nil. Thanks for the reply.